# The Microsoft Graph API returned a different threadID for the same mail

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In our application we make calls to the Microsoft Graph API to fetch the email header data.
During the initial call to the api we received the following conversationId details for an email

```
{"conversationId":"AAQkADVhMzU1YWY5LWVkNGQtNGZjOC1hMjJmLTk0MzIxMGQzMzRhMQAQAA8kZ_w6rdxIsHkFk+h7byQ="}
```

And a few seconds later when we made a similar request for the same email, we received a different conversationId

```
{"conversationId":"AAQkADVhMzU1YWY5LWVkNGQtNGZjOC1hMjJmLTk0MzIxMGQzMzRhMQAQAA8kZ_w6rdxIsHkFk_h7byQ="}
```

Now the expectation here is that the value of the conversationId should always remain the same.
In the above scenario the only difference in the 2 conversationId returned is the '+' being replaced with the '_'

- `AAQkADVhMzU1YWY5LWVkNGQtNGZjOC1hMjJmLTk0MzIxMGQzMzRhMQAQAA8kZ_w6rdxIsHkFk+h7byQ=`
- `AAQkADVhMzU1YWY5LWVkNGQtNGZjOC1hMjJmLTk0MzIxMGQzMzRhMQAQAA8kZ_w6rdxIsHkFk_h7byQ=`

**Detailed Steps:-**

- The owa mail dom is parsed to fetch the conversationId

  > `AAQkADVhMzU1YWY5LWVkNGQtNGZjOC1hMjJmLTk0MzIxMGQzMzRhMQAQAA8kZ_w6rdxIsHkFk+h7byQ=`
- Using this conversationId we make a call to the MS Graph API and get the details including the messageId which we store in our DB as a primary key
- A few minutes later, we make another MS Graph API call, this time using the messageId, and in response we get a different conversationId

  > `AAQkADVhMzU1YWY5LWVkNGQtNGZjOC1hMjJmLTk0MzIxMGQzMzRhMQAQAA8kZ_w6rdxIsHkFk_h7byQ=`

**Question:-**

Is it possible by any chance that + and _ are interchangable

Comment: There isn't a lot here to go on. How you're getting the `threadId`? How are you attempting to use this value in your application?

Comment: Have updated my question with the steps

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't assume Exchange identifiers are interchangeable across platforms. Over the years, Exchange has used a crazy number of different formats for identifiers. This is likely the crux of the issue here.

There are some mechanisms for [converting between them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-identifiers-in-exchange#converting-identifiers) but I generally advise against it unless you've got no other option.

I'm not sure why/how you're parsing the OWS DOM but I'm frankly more surprised the identifiers are that close than I am that it doesn't work as expected. If you want to pull the message from Graph from within OWA, I would use an [Outlook Web Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/) for this. The add-in framework includes a [convertToRestId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api#get-the-item-id) method that returns an identifier you can use with Microsoft Graph:

```
function getItemRestId() {
  if (Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName === 'OutlookIOS') {
    // itemId is already REST-formatted
    return Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
  } else {
    // Convert to an item ID for API v2.0
    return Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(
      Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId,
      Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0
    );
  }
}
```

As for the `+` vs `_`, this comes down to the encoding format. There are multiple flavors of Base64. Standard In standard Base64, the 62nd character is `+` and the 63rd is `/`.  This presents a problem when you want to use Base64 in a URL as `+` and `/` are reserved characters. To get around this, you need a URL safe variant of Base64. There are several such variants out there. The most common is **base64url** (defined in [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)) which swaps out the `-` for the 62nd and `_` for the 63rd.